# Api-Platform : Filter and inheritance issue

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I've two classes with a custom filter:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"store" = "Store", "book_store" = "BookStore"})
 * @ApiResource(normalizationContext = {"groups" = {"api_read"}}, collectionOperations = {"GET"}, itemOperations = {"GET"})
 * @ApiFilter(OrSearchFilter::class, properties={"title", "text"})
 */

class Store
{
  ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource(normalizationContext = {"groups" = {"api_book_read", "api_read"}}, collectionOperations = {"GET"}, itemOperations = {"GET"})
 * @ApiFilter(OrSearchFilter::class, properties={"title", "text", "book.book.authors.title", "book.book.theme.title"})
 */
class BookStore extends Store {
  ...
}
```

When I try to filter on my entity 'BookStore', my filter 'OrSearchFilter' is called twice: the first SQL query is for 'BookStore' and the second for 'Store'. So, if I try to filter on 'book.book.authors.title', I have no result because Api-Platform calls my 'OrSearchFilter' of my entity 'Store'.

How to make my filter only be called once for my entity 'BookStore'?